# Significance of dummy variables in probit regression

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I am an undergraduate student working on some projects using probit regression.  I have a question on dummy variables that I was hoping someone could help me with (which I think stems from an incomplete understanding of the theroy).

I am using SAS to create a probit model (also logit models) for a binary dependent variable.  The first explanatory parameter I added to the model turned out to be significant (p-value <0.05), as I expected based on my intuition of the hypothesis.  I then added a set of 25 binary dummy variables, which each represented one single qualitative variable that had 25 possible values.  (example: 25 ice cream flavors, 1st dummy variable:  chocolate (y/n)?  2nd:  mint (y/n)?.  Note, there are no combinations.  You can't have chocolate AND mint, only choclate OR mint)

When I ran the model with my first explanatory variable and all the dummy variables, not a single dummy variable came up significant.  I then re-ran the model, but instead of including all the dummy variables, I included the ones I thought should have been significant (this was 3 of them).  When I ran the model with my first parameter and the 3 dummy variables, they were all significant!

I don't understand why I am getting this behaivor... and also what it means for the model.  Is it bad practice if I only include the 3 dummy variables, because I know they are significant?  Should I try every possible combination of the 25 variables to see which has the most significant variables (may be computationally impossible...)?  Should I consider none of them significant because of the initial run?

(By the way, I have ~10,000 observations in my sample.)

Comment: include only 24 of your dummies not 25, then do you see a difference?

Comment: If I included 1-24, no difference... but if I included 2-25, I got great results. Note that dummy_variable_22 had no observations.  This does remind me, in my regression course when we would create a dummy variable for the months we would only add 11 dummy varaibles.  Does this have something to do with setting a "control" for the experiment/model?  If you could explain this theory or point me somewhere I can read about it that woudl be great!

Comment: The problem could be multicollinearity which should be discussed in any regression analysis book ...

Comment: Will read wiki page.  Thank you for help

Comment: I've always found it annoying to see the term "dummy variable" used to mean an indicator variable.  The term "dummy variable" also means a _bound_ variable as opposed to a _free_ variable, and that is _not_ about lists of zeros and ones.  "Dummy" is a very good term for "bound"; it implies a certain contempt for bound variables, which is appropriate.  But indicator variables (taking $0$ or $1$ as values) don't deserve the contempt and shouldn't be called that.  Unfortunately it's a widespread usage among statisticians. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If some of your predictor variables are highly correlated then this sort of thing could happen.

Comment: Maybe 10,000 is a big enough sample to judge whether probit or logit is a better model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dummy variables, everything is relative to the omitted group. So lets say in the first regression, you included all categories of 1-24, if none are significant, it suggests that you cannot tell the difference between those values *and the value for the 25th category*. This could, for example, be a function of the implied coefficient for the 25th category being very noisy and you are unable to get a precise estimate.

In your second regression, your omitted category is now, "everything that is not one the three main values". This is obviously a much different reference group.

In one of your comments, you said "If I included 1-24, no difference... but if I included 2-25, I got great results." But, this does not make sense. The results should be the same. Here's how to see this. First, run the the regression including 1-24. Note the coefficient and p-value on type 2. Then run the regression with 2-25. Now, test the difference between the coefficients on type 25 and type 2. It should be the same as the test on type 2 in the previous case.